# React component not rendering after checking for Authentication

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-component

So basically I'm trying to create a protected route for my application and I have another function that checks with the server API whether the client is authenticated correctly.
Unfortunately, because of how React Hooks works, the state isn't updated directly and if I try to have a redirect when the user isn't authenticated, it just sends me there.
So when you reload the page, since the State is also reset, on the first render it will treat me as if I'm not logged in (even though I am) and send me to the login page.

So what I thought is I can await until it gets the response and then render with `isAuth(ctx).then(...)` , however, it just doesn't render anything.

Here is the router structure I have:

```
    <BrowserRouter>
        <AppContext.Provider value={ctx}>
            <Route path="/dashboard">
                <Switch>
                    <LoginRoute exact path="/dashboard/login" component={LogInDash} />
                    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard/create" component={CreateProperty} />
                    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard/list" component={ListDash} />
                    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard/edit/:id" component={EditProperty} />
                    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/dashboard/delete/:id" component={DeleteProperty} />
                </Switch>
            </Route>
        </AppContext.Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
```

And here is the function to fetch from the API:

```
export const isAuth = async (ctx: React.ComponentState): Promise<boolean> => {
const fetchRes = fetch(`${APIURL}/api/auth`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    credentials: 'include',
})
    .then((res) => {
        res.json();
        if (res.status === 200) {
            ctx.auth.set(true);
            console.log('successful verification');
            return true;
        } else {
            ctx.auth.set(false);
            console.log('Token not verified');
            return false;
        }
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return false;
    });
return fetchRes;
```

};

And finally, here is the ProtectedRouter code:

```
export function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }: any): any {
    const ctx = React.useContext(AppContext);
    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                isAuth(ctx);
                /* isAuth(ctx).then((res) => { */
                if (ctx.auth.get) {
                    return <Component {...rest} {...props} />;
                } else {
                    /* return <Unauthorized />; */
                    return <Redirect to="/dashboard/login" />;
                    /* window.location.href = '/dashboard/login'; */
                }
                /* }); */
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

I feel like I'm just missing something stupid or there is some mistake in the concept that I'm trying to apply.

Thanks for even reading this far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would introduce a new `isReady` state and `await` for the authentication within a `useEffect` hook. Until it is not ready the app can show up a loading `<span>` for example.

See my suggestion as the following:

```
export function ProtectedRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }: any): any {
    const ctx = React.useContext(AppContext);
    const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
       const runAuth = async () => {
           await isAuth(ctx);
           setIsReady(true);
       }

       runAuth();
    }, [])

    return (
        <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
                if (!isReady} {
                   return <span>Loading ...</span>
                }

                if (ctx.auth.get) {
                    return <Component {...rest} {...props} />;
                } else {
                    /* return <Unauthorized />; */
                    return <Redirect to="/dashboard/login" />;
                    /* window.location.href = '/dashboard/login'; */
                }
                /* }); */
            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Suggested read is [Using the Effect Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

Comment: This worked like a charm, adding a new State variable and making use of UseEffect did the trick.
I was thinking of a way to implement an async function that also had access to `ctx` and didn't think of making use of useEffect...
Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: @Belf Awesome, happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
// NOTE: Is this firing correctly.. doesn't seem to fire if signed in .... and then try to go to profile or inventory page directly .... always redirects to '/' it seems
const AuthedRoute = ({ component: Component, user, ...rest }) => (
    <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) =>
          user.authenticated === null ? null : user.authenticated ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
        }
    />
);
```